# Protected images folder Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, protected

I want to protect a lot of my `png` and `JPEG` (actually in the drawable folder), because it's very easy to decompile an APK and take the images.
How can I make another coded folder and set `android:src` for ImageView in XML layouts?
Thanks

Comment: Convert image into byte array, xor every second byte with some mask and write back image. Every time you load image xor it with same mask and load image. I would do it like that if you don't want to use some special encryption on whole image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should have to encrypt the image using linear algebra techniques. convert your image in matrix and then reverse this mat for encryption or you have many techniques to encrypt this mat.Some thing like this.

```
    public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

hope this will help.